# Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, .net-4.0, sqlclient

I'm trying to implement an asynchronous search "engine", but i'm facing some difficulties.

For some reason a [SqlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is thrown every once in a while stating that:

> *"The variable name '@input' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure."*

[image: Sample application]

**Sample application**

The following code targets the [sys.messages](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187382.aspx) table, so all you have to do is change the *connection string*.

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me.input = New TextBox() With {.Dock = DockStyle.Top, .TabIndex = 0}
        Me.output = New RichTextBox() With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill, .TabIndex = 1, .ReadOnly = True, .WordWrap = False}
        Me.Controls.AddRange({Me.output, Me.input})
    End Sub

    Private Sub Search(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles input.TextChanged
        Dim input As String = Me.input.Text
        Static command As SqlCommand
        Static source As CancellationTokenSource
        If (Not command Is Nothing) Then command.Cancel()
        If (Not source Is Nothing) Then source.Cancel()
        command = New SqlCommand()
        source = New CancellationTokenSource()
        Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() Me.SearchingAsync(input, command, source.Token))
    End Sub

    Private Sub SearchingAsync(input As String, command As SqlCommand, token As CancellationToken)
        Dim [error] As Exception = Nothing
        Dim cancelled As Boolean = False
        Dim result As List(Of sys_message) = Nothing
        Try
            Using connection As New SqlConnection("Server=instance\name;Database=name;Trusted_Connection=True;")
                connection.Open()
                command.Connection = connection
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                command.CommandText = "select * from sys.messages where [text] like '%' + @input + '%';"
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@input", input)
                Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                    result = New List(Of sys_message)()
                    Do While (reader.Read() AndAlso (Not token.IsCancellationRequested))
                        result.Add(New sys_message() With {
                            .message_id = CInt(reader.Item("message_id")),
                            .language_id = CInt(reader.Item("language_id")),
                            .severity = CInt(reader.Item("severity")),
                            .is_event_logged = CBool(reader.Item("is_event_logged")),
                            .text = CStr(reader.Item("text"))
                        })
                    Loop
                End Using
            End Using
            cancelled = token.IsCancellationRequested
        Catch ex As SqlException When ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("operation cancelled by user")
            cancelled = True
        Catch ex As ThreadAbortException
            cancelled = True
        Catch ex As OperationCanceledException
            cancelled = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            [error] = ex
        Finally
            Me.Invoke(
                Sub()
                    'If (String.CompareOrdinal(input, Me.input.Text) = 0) Then
                    If (Not [error] Is Nothing) Then
                        Me.output.Text = String.Concat("Input='", input, "', Output={Result: 'error', Type: '", [error].GetType.Name, "', Message: '", [error].Message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " "), "'}", Environment.NewLine, Me.output.Text).Trim()
                    ElseIf (cancelled) Then
                        Me.output.Text = String.Concat("Input='", input, "', Output={Result: 'cancelled'}", Environment.NewLine, Me.output.Text).Trim()
                    Else
                        Me.output.Text = String.Concat("Input='", input, "', Output={Result: 'success', Count: ", result.Count, "}", Environment.NewLine, Me.output.Text).Trim()
                    End If
                    'End If
                End Sub
            )
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private WithEvents input As TextBox
    Private WithEvents output As RichTextBox

    Private Class sys_message
        Public message_id As Integer
        Public language_id As Integer
        Public severity As Integer
        Public is_event_logged As Boolean
        Public text As String
    End Class

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're inadvertently sharing `SqlCommand` objects between multiple calls to `SearchingAsync`. I'd remove the outer code that attempts to deal with trying to cancel those and just let `SearchingAsync` create its own, unshared instances.

At the same time, you might want to consider using the async API's that `SqlCommand` exposes, e.g. [`ExecuteReaderAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204838%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allow you to pass a cancellation token to them, so that cancellation is all handled by your single cancellation token.

You also need to ensure that the correct cancellation token is passed to the right invocation of your method:

```
Private Sub Search(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles input.TextChanged
    Dim input As String = Me.input.Text
    Static source As CancellationTokenSource
    If (Not source Is Nothing) Then source.Cancel()
    source = New CancellationTokenSource()
    Dim token = source.Token
    Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() Me.SearchingAsync(input, token))
End Sub
```

---

Basically, at this line of code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() Me.SearchingAsync(input, command, source.Token))
```

when it completes, all that you know is that, at some future point in time, it's going to run this:

```
Me.SearchingAsync(input, command, source.Token)
```

At that future point in time, it's going to load a `SqlCommand` object from the `command` variable and then invoke `SearchingAsync` (and, similarly, `source` is loaded at this point)

But, what if, in the meantime, your `Search` method has run again? It's cancelled the `command` and `source` that were originally intended for this method call, and it's replaced them with new copies. And it's scheduled *another* task to run `SearchingAsync` in the future. Those two calls end up referencing the same `command` objects and so it ends up with the `@input` parameter added to it twice.

Comment: I'm using `.net 4.0` so `ExecuteReaderAsync` is not available. I know that I'm inadvertently sharing the objects, but I don't see any other way to do this async and at the same time support cancellation.

Comment: Well, inside of your `SearchingAsync` method, once it's created it's private, non-shared `SqlCommand` object, have it use [`CancellationToken.Register`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321635(v=vs.110).aspx) to add a delegate that will call `Cancel` on the command if cancellation is requested. Something like `token.Register(Sub() command.Cancel())` should do, or possibly even just `token.Register(command.Cancel)` might work.

Comment: That is a brilliant idea! Thanks! * bowing *